# Rest JSON with Jackson @type not added in json

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, jackson

I added jackson to my rest jersey project because the default json mapper of jersey gives JSON Objects when list element size is 1 and giving JSON Arrays when element size was 2 or more.

So jackson works well with that part, but the default json mapper of jersey (idk what is the default) can give me a propperty called @type, when implementing jackson the propperty is not added in the JSON return.

before i was ussing: @XmlType(name = "TypeName") in the @XmlRootElement
now i'm trying with @JsonTypeInfo, @JsonTypeName with jackson 2.5.4 and 2.22.2 but no success.

How can i add the @type propperty?

Edit 1: (Adding web.xml)

in web.xml i have this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Edit 2: (adding jackson versions)

```
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.7.4 
jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.2
jackson-annotations:2.7.4
jackson-jaxrs-base:2.7.4
jackson-databind:2.7.4
jackson-core:2.7.4
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.7.4
jersey-entity-filtering:2.22.2
jersey-common:2.22.2
```

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I'm ussing JBoss AS 7.1.1

Comment: Have you done any confirmation checks to see that your Jackson 2.x is even being used? AFAIK, Jackson 1.x is the default JSON provider in JBoss 7

Comment: When i was trying to implement Jackson, the server thrown errors like "method not found exception" i had to add more pom dependencies to make it work. how can i test the version?

Comment: Did you add the [jackson-jaxrs-json-provider](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider)? Or just jackson-databind? You need the jaxrs provider, and you need to register the JacksonJsonProvider with your jaxrs application.

Comment: yes, i added jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.7.4 and those: jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.2, jackson-annotations:2.7.4, jackson-jaxrs-base:2.7.4. jackson-databind_2.7.4, jackson-core:2.7.4, jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.7.4, jersey-entity-filtering:2.22.2, jersey-common:2.22.2

Comment: I edited question adding web.xml and jackson versions.

Comment: You still need to register the provider. Try adding this package to the list of packages to scan in your web.xml `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json`. You can separate the two with a comma. And get rid of the `POJOMappingFeature`

Comment: ok I will add the package and tell you what happened , thanks in advance .

Comment: i added the com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json package, and the webservice throws this error: StandardWrapper.Throwable: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: The URI scheme vfs of the URI vfs:/...my_project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.7.4.jar/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/ is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs.

Comment: this is the modified part: `<param-value>my.package.webservice,com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json</param-value>`

Comment: oh! sorry i didn't remove the POJOMappingFeature, i'm retrying without POJOMappingFeature

Comment: i removed POJOMappingFeature but error keeps there:  StandardWrapper.Throwable: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: The URI scheme vfs of the URI .....  is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Like @peeskillet said:

> Jackson 1.x is the default JSON provider in JBoss 7

I had to remove provided jackson from JBoss AS 7.1.1, got steps [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/789843#789843)

I changed web.xml servlet like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I had to Create the class "my.package.MyApplication":

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        super("my.package.webservice;com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json");
    }

}
```

And jackson 2.x is working now, thank you @peeskillet for helping me.

next was create a propperty called @type like this:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "@type")
String xmlType = "TypeName";
```

And JSON returns @type propperty.